# Yahoo Mail behind a watchgaurd

Tags: proxy, firewall, yahoo-mail

I'm getting the following error when I open a thread in the new Yahoo mail behind our watchguard firewall

> Response denied by WatchGuard HTTP Proxy.
>
> Reason: header 'Content-Type' denied rule='Default'
>   value='multipart/form-data'
>
> Please contact your administrator for assistance.
>
> More Details:
>
> Method: POST
>
> Host: in-mg61.mail.yahoo.com
>
> Path:
>   /ws/v3/batch?appid=YahooMailNeo&prime=0&wssid=vLZ3JPa0h51&windowid=111306989&r=1381508761488

here is the screenshot
[image]

I have googled it, searched every where and I cannot for the love of god figure this out.

Comment: As per the message itself, I would talk to your administrator, about the problems you face.  Furthermore you don't indicate what browser your using, if it happens on any other browser while using the same proxy, or steps you have attempted to solve this.

Comment: this is embarassing, it is IT asking for help, this happens only in the new interface, the basic opens mail just fine. Tested on Safari, IR, FF and chrome

Comment: So it happens in multiple browsers.  This means its either an incompatability with the changes Yahoo had made or it is caused by a single setting within Watchguard that isn't currently compatible.  Have you contacted `WatchGuard Technologies` to verify this isn't a known problem?

Comment: i have emailed them , waiting for reply, but for now we have had users to use old basic version

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into your HTTP proxy and add multipart/form-data as an allowed content type.  Have the user restart their browser and it should work.  I just resolved the same issue.

** also suggest going into the same proxy and under the General Settings check the box to allow range request through unmodified. **

Thanks